# How do I name a item without italics and make it unbreakable?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I have a minecraft server and I want to make a pickaxe that is named without italics and is unbreakable. This is the command I tried:

```
Give [playername] WOOD_PICKAXE {Unbreakable:1,Display:{LocName:"Tier 1 pickaxe"}}
```

Comment: Please look up a command tutorial. I can already see at least 5 mistakes in the syntax, not even including the problem you asked about. The [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com) is your friend, as well as [Google](https://www.google.com). And if something doesn't work, you need to give information about what it does. Does it give an error message, does it blow up your house or does it spawn a million chickens? So far you've said "I tried this." and I think "Ok, fine. So what's your problem?"

Answer (score 2):

give @p wooden_pickaxe{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"no italics!\",\"italic\":\"false\"}"},Unbreakable:true}

Answer (score 1):

give [playername] wooden_pickaxe 1 0 {Unbreakable:1,display:{LocName:"Tier 1 pickaxe"}}
You just don't need put capital letter on the display tag.